# Display multiple query results in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using MSSQL Management Studio on daily basis, makes me look like such a fool when using MySQL: How can I combine irrelevant queries in one without any join intended? I am basically just looking for a simple view of a couple of tables:

SELECT * FROM FOO LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM BOO LIMIT 1

Definitely join and union does not work since they supposedly do not have any shared columns.

Thank!

Comment: Is the DB design itself wrong !! why dont you run the queries one after other as they dont have any relation each other:-)

Comment: Good point but all I want is a simultaneous view over two independent tables just for the sake of efficiency. Anyway not a big deal. I'm probably just using a wrong tool. A spreadsheet does the job! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in the one result table?

```
SELECT * FROM FOO LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM BOO LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I had already tried the semicolon. Doesn't help. I get the 1064 error:  You have an error in your Query syntax; check the manual....